# Django generic.ListVIew: display list item's details on the same page (~ combine ListView and DetailView)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-generic-views

What I want is to display the clicked ListView item's details on the same page that contains the ListView (roughly speaking, combine generic.ListView with generic.DetailView). What I've done is:

generic.ListView of Contacts:

```
from .models import Contact
from django.views import generic

class ContactList(generic.ListView):
    model = Contact
    context_object_name = 'contacts'
    template_name = 'contacts/list.html'
```

The contacts/list.html template includes a JS Fetch request (GET) to get the clicked item:

```
{% block content %}
{% if contacts %}
    <ul>
    {% for contact in contacts %}
        <li><a id="{{ contact.id }}" onClick="showDetails(this.id)">{{ contact.first_name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    No contacts. 
{% endif %}

<div id='contactDetail'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showDetails(contactId){
    console.log(contactId);
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/contacts/${contactId}`, {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        },
    })
    .then(response => {
        // should 500 be processed?
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        //Perform actions with the response data from the view
        window.onload = function() {
            // build html markup next
            document.getElementById("contactDetail").innerHTML= ...;
        } 
    })
  }
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

The Django view that handles this Fetch-GET request is:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

def contact_details(request, contact_id):
    contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=contact_id)
    contact = {k: v for k, v in model_to_dict(contact).items() if v}
    return JsonResponse(contact)
```

Is it the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

There is almost nothing wrong with your way.

Although production, you should use [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview).
This way there shouldn't be too much data and I think it would be better to return all the fields together with a list, but hide the extra fields at first and just unhide them on click.